# Decompose array so every 2nd element is in a different array

Tags: php, arrays

So I would like to take an "unsorted" array and get every second element out of the "unsorted" array and put it into a new array, so what's left is two arrays.

```
$unsorted = array("present","Bob","late","Jessie","late","Carl","present","Jessica","absent","Adam","present","Hope");
```

I thought of creating a `for` loop, but I couldn't find any functions to create the two arrays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: This isn't sorting. Sorting is putting an array in order.

Comment: Why doesn't a `for` loop work? If the index is even, push the element onto the first array. If it's odd, push the element onto the second array.

Comment: Why do you want two arrays? It looks like this should be an associative array, like `["Bob" => "present", "Jessie" => "late", ...]`

Comment: @Barmar How would you make an associative array using a loop in PHP?

Comment: Use a `for` loop that increments by two, and do `$result[$unsorted[$i+1]] = $unsorted[$i];`

Comment: Why not create it as an associative array in the first place, instead of alternating like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using the classic `foreach` loop.

```
$unsorted = array("present","Bob","late","Jessie","late","Carl","present","Jessica","absent","Adam","present","Hope");

$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach( $unsorted as $key => $val ) {
    if ( $key % 2 ) $array2[] = $val;
    else $array1[] =  $val;
}
```

`$array1` will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => present
    [1] => late
    [2] => late
    [3] => present
    [4] => absent
    [5] => present
)
```

`$array2` will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bob
    [1] => Jessie
    [2] => Carl
    [3] => Jessica
    [4] => Adam
    [5] => Hope
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but need some understanding:

```
$unsorted = array("present","Bob","late","Jessie","late","Carl","present","Jessica","absent","Adam","present","Hope");
$sorted = array_map(null, ...array_chunk($unsorted, 2));
print_r($sorted);
```

Comment: You should explain how it works, since it "needs some understanding".